# Попытка подключения к базе данных завершилась неудачей

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Помогите разрешить проблему: создал БД в SQL Server(Enterprise edition), работал с ней все время - все ок. В один момент отключил от сервера в MSVS2019. Сейчас пытаюсь добавить подключение к ней, а мне пишет: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталкивался или знает в чем может крыться залог неудачи - поделитесь.
Тоже самое пишет, когда пытался установить эту БД в качестве источника данных для dataGridView.

При попытке подключения к БД через SSMS:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка в строке подключения. Покажите её.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мало-ли кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой при работе с MySql.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я пытаюсь подключить через Обозреватель серверов -> Подключиться к БД -> Открывается форма, где я выбираю "Прикрепить файл базы данных", указываю путь до файла. Ну и после нажатия ОК всплывает эта ошибка.

Comment: `где я выбираю "Прикрепить файл базы данных"` такая опция разве есть для `SQL Server(Enterprise edition)`? Разве вы не должны выбрать сервер и затем выбрать доступную БД вместо поисков файлов?

Comment: @tym32167 это функция есть в MSVS2019, из которой я пытаюсь это сделать.

Comment: вы через sql server management studio можете к свой БД подклчиться?

Comment: @tym32167, пытался, но не получается. Ошибку добавил в описание вопроса.

Comment: @tym32167, запустил ssms с правами админа и о чудо - она подключилась. Только вопрос: как в таком случае можно открыть в MSVS, потому что там идет работа с этой БД в подключенном режиме?

Comment: запустите MSVS с правами админа?